# how to implement promise.allSettled in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this code to search if a user is in the list or not. The thing is, I need to implement the calls to findOne in parallel. How can I add the promise.allSettled?

As is the code, how can I create multiple calls to findOne? I have reviewed the documentation of the Promises but I don't know how to implement it in this case.

```
const findOne = (list, { key, value }) => {  
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {  
        const element = list.find(element => element[key] === value); 
        
        setTimeout(() => {  
            element 
            ? resolve(element.name) 
            :reject(new Error('ERROR: Element not found')); 
        }, 2000); 
    });
  }
  
  const users = [  
  {
    name: 'Carlos', 
    rol: 'Teacher' 
  },
  {
    name: 'Ana', 
    rol: 'Boss' 
  }
  ];


console.log('findOne User'); 

async function fetchData(){ 
  try { 
    const findUser = await findOne(users,{key: 'name', value: 'Carlos'}); 
    console.log("user:" + findUser); 
  }catch(err){ 
    console.log(err.message); 
  }
    
}

fetchData();
```

I have this code to search if a user is in the list or not. The thing is, I need to implement the calls to findOne in parallel. How can I add the promise.allSettled?

As is the code, how can I create multiple calls to findOne? I have reviewed the documentation of the Promises but I don't know how to implement it in this case.

I don't know how to try it anymore... thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Why are you using Promises in the first place? `list.find()` is synchronous

Comment: I see no attempt of using `Promise.allSettled` in your code? You should have a go at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would then want to pass a number of names to find to `fetchData`, and map those names to calls to `findOne`. Then call `Promise.allSettled` on the promises that you get back from that mapping. Finally deal with the returned settled-array as you wish:

```js
const findOne = (list, { key, value }) => new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {  
    const element = list.find(element => element[key] === value); 
    setTimeout(() => element ? resolve(element.name) 
                             : reject(new Error('ERROR: Element not found'))
    , 2000); 
});
  
const users = [{name: 'Carlos', rol: 'Teacher'}, {name: 'Ana',  rol: 'Boss'}];

console.log('findOne User'); 

async function fetchData(names) {
  const promises = names.map(value => findOne(users, {key: 'name', value }));
  let results = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
  console.log(results);
}

fetchData(["Carlos", "Helen", "Ana"]);
```